# Jquery.validate how to set an error message next to validated element

Tags: jquery, validation

```html
 <p class="e-cp">
      <label for="cp"><span class="red">*</span>C.P.:</label>
      <input type="text" id="cp" name="cp" maxlength="5" value="12345"/>
      <a href="#" id="cp_no" name="cp_no" class="cp_help">No recuerdo mi C.P.</a>
      <label id="error_1"></label>
 </p>
```

I am trying to add the error message in the < label id = " error_1 " > and make it disappear when the input is focus, but I have not found how to do it.

I am using this rule:

```
 cp:{
      required: {
           depends: function(element) {
                if ($("input[name='cp']").val() != "") {          
                     return false;
                } else {
                     return true;
                }                  
           }
      },
```

And I've been trying to set the functionality in the else statment after the return true.

Comment: Can you provide [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net) of what you currently have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to implement this functionality by yourself if you are using the validator from [Jquery validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) (*which I think you are, guessing from your code snippet*).

You would just need to set the `required` rule as *true* for your `cp` element. For removing the errors on focus, set the `focusCleanup` option to *true*.

Here is working **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2UCaD/)**

```
$("form").validate({
    debug: true,
    focusCleanup: true,
    rules: {
        cp: "required"
    }
});
```

Also, you don't need to add your own label field `error_1`, as the validator by itself does append the error label after the element having errors. If you really need it, you have to override the default `error` function of validator, more relevant stuff can be found [Here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).